# BigQuery update nested table based on condition

Tags: google-bigquery

This is the code:

```
UPDATE `xxx.xxx.gift_test_1`
SET PaymentLines = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('gift_card' AS PaymentType) FROM UNNEST(PaymentLines) WHERE PaymentMethod = 'gift_card')
WHERE true
```

The problem here that I need to update Payment type to 'gift_card' ONLY where PaymentMethod = to 'gift_card', but my code updates EVERYTHING  and PaymentMethod and PaymentType to 'gift_card' after it executed

**UPDATE 1.0**

```
UPDATE `xxx.xxx.gift_test_1`
SET PaymentLines = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE ('gift_card' AS PaymentType)
  FROM UNNEST(PaymentLines) as pay
)
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from unnest(PaymentLines) as pay WHERE pay.PaymentMethod = 'gift_card')
```

This code update all PaymentType to the 'gift_card', so in this cercumstances WHERE clause do not work.

**UPDATE 2.0**

WHAT I HAVE:
[image]

WHAT I NEED:
[image]

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Not sure if I'm using tags correctly

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard ANy ideas, ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
UPDATE `xxx.xxx.gift_test_1`
SET PaymentLines = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * 
      REPLACE(IF(PaymentMethod = 'gift_card', 'gift_card', PaymentType) AS PaymentType)
    FROM UNNEST(PaymentLines) AS pay
  )
WHERE true
```

Comment: I just got the same answer yesterday :D, Thank you) but the funny part is that it is 100% exactly the same )